# Obtaining a random value using Groovy JsonSlurper

Tags: groovy, collections, jsonslurper

I'm new to Groovy and trying to understand the best way of approaching this. Apologies for an elementary question.

Given a Json file `vehicles.json` of:

```
{
  "prod": [
    {
      "id": "CAR LARGE",
      "vehicle": "102920",
      "name": "BMW 325"
    },
    {
      "id": "CAR MEDIUM",
      "vehicle": "192039",
      "name": "VOLVO V40"
    },
    {
      "id": "CAR SMALL",
      "vehicle": "29303",
      "name": "SMART 500"
    }
  ], 
  "preprod": [
   {///entries for this environment...
```

I want to pick a random Car for a given environment, then extract it's `vehicle` and `name` properties into List of 2 for future use (in reality the list is very long)

This method will get a random vehicle number:

```
    def getVehicle() {
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def envVehiclesList = jsonSlurper.parseText(new File('src/main/resources/data/vehicles.json').text)

        List<String> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();
        switch (System.getProperty("env")) {
            case "prod":
                vehicleList = (envVehiclesList.prod*.vehicle)
                break;
            case "preprod":
                vehicleList = (envVehiclesList.preprod*.vehicle)
                break;
            case "dev":
                vehicleList = (envVehiclesList.dev*.vehicle)
                break;
            default:
                vehicleList = "18292" as List<String>
        }

        def rand = new Random()
        def randomVehicle = vehicleList.get(rand.nextInt(vehicleList.size()))
        log.info("Random Base Vehicle: {}", randomVehicle)
        return randomVehicle
    }
```

This gives me a random `vehicle` e.g. `192039`. I need to be able to extract the `name` associated with the randomly chosen `vehicle` and store it in a List or Object so I can extract both for future use e.g. `randomVehicle` stores both `29303, SMART 500` and I can get by index from a list or use a getter if stored in an Object.

Any suggestions would help my learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def input = """
{
  "prod": [
    {
      "id": "CAR LARGE",
      "vehicle": "102920",
      "name": "BMW 325"
    },
    {
      "id": "CAR MEDIUM",
      "vehicle": "192039",
      "name": "VOLVO V40"
    },
    {
      "id": "CAR SMALL",
      "vehicle": "29303",
      "name": "SMART 500"
    }
  ]
}
"""

def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def envVehiclesList = jsonSlurper.parseText(input)
def env = "prod"
def vehicleList = []
    
switch (env) {
    case "prod":
    vehicleList = (envVehiclesList.prod)
    break;
    case "preprod":
    vehicleList = (envVehiclesList.preprod)
    break;
    case "dev":
    vehicleList = (envVehiclesList.dev)
    break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Environment: $env")
}

def rand = new Random()
def randomVehicle = vehicleList.get(rand.nextInt(vehicleList.size()))
println("Random Base Vehicle: $randomVehicle")
```

Just don't select `.vehicle`, then you have all the data.
Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJyVkU1PwkAQhu_9FZONhzYhTQU5gPEASgymhIQvD8ZDpSOslN1muxSU8N-dXQqC-NnDZjvvzDOz88b4DFykCw1XwBhz1g4AS5WMWR0e6A6wtidFuYmx60YPwkbvtsVKOyHHKR8naNTzoFwrBx-SiOY23uzcQ6VcZTa-KX0H7rRu2sPO12TiVmqn5FE3HHVhdBH8xu53GmH4JbpcqwSVUzIV9AZQDXZkOh-djWO25MS0tpdMin6yUCkqWp7AJUyUlPmrbwT_7kN1PZuPIh9tm2Yhz8zCDwh-GqkMB7jSrrVjX2J8sX7YQDF1Uf_waCdzsiXX4ym4lO4VTx9HGe6MtIHjSvfTML7J9Gzik8JodnkEwf9w8AdUjPnfMJR4gqD3R4tE1wufAPRUyaVdfDtJcBIlDTVZzFHo1mqMqeZSuGwoZkIuBbREzpUURq3DGbVjHnlpd6oiERcG9ugq54Vfyv4UY1HCwcj-BLVrdF-QY22h3UMx42_oep7npIoLndAUWy40zRIKIE1x1IB5-3eZ7x0PBQdm)